# Read user utterance in the dialog after intent matches

Tags: node.js, botframework

Hi I am looking for the code where I can read the user utterance in the dialog and find entity to execute business logic. I am using RegEx recognizer instead of LUIS. I am able to invoke the proper intent with user input. The below is code

```
bot.recognizer(new builder.RegExpRecognizer( 'searchProductsIntent', /^search products in \w+$|^please get products of \w+$/i));
bot.dialog("searchProductsKk", function (session) {
    session.send("I am intent");
    session.endConversation("Ok, I'm intent.");

    //Logic:I want to read the user utterance here for eg., search products in **kodak**. I want to read the search term "kodak" from utterance to search kodak products. 

}).triggerAction({ matches: 'searchProductsIntent' });
```

I couldn't find related sample code anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recieve the input message via the second parameter of `IDialogWaterfallStep` function. Please consider the following code snippet:

```
bot.dialog("searchProductsKk", function (session,args,next) {
   // args.intent.matched[0] is the user utterance.
   console.log(args.intent.matched[0])

}).triggerAction({
    matches: 'searchProductsIntent'
});
```